# Analytics.js, phonegap doesn't call the callback function

Tags: javascript, cordova, google-analytics

I have followed the following tutorial : http://www.blastam.com/blog/index.php/2013/07/ga-universal-analytics-phonegap-mobile-apps/

It's working except if the page changes just after an event (a click for exemple)

For exemple when a user click on a button I have the following code:

```
_gaq.push([ '_trackPageview', 'object' ]);//work correctly on a website using ga.js
$(location).attr('href', "index.html");
```

Since I'm using analytics.js in the phonegap app I have the following code working when I replace the sleep function with an alert.

```
_gaq = {
    'push': function (lst) {
        var boolean = true;
        ga('send', 'pageview', {
            'page': lst[1],
            'hitCallback': function () {
                console.log("done");
                boolean = false;
            }
        });

        function sleep() {
            if (boolean === true) {
                setTimeout(sleep, 50);
                return;
            }
        }
        sleep();
    }
};
```

Any ideas?

Comment: make sure variables are not null, i had a similar problem, that was the reason

Comment: @kangoroo I have printed `lst[1]` and `boolean` and they always have a value. But the `sleep` function is called only once.

Comment: might be the timeout problem too, also try it as window.setTimeout

Comment: @kangoroo Still the same problem :/ . Maybe I should replace all my ga tags by analytics tags